# Squid3 proxy Cannot write log file

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi, squid, debian-wheezy

I installed Squid3 on Rasbian, and did some minor configuration. Then I set it up to cache to an auto mounting usb drive.

I was looking over the logs and found only `TCP_MISS`. I was hoping after a little bit of using Squid with the I'd see some hits. I looked in the cache (the ufs tree is there) and it appears to be caching files.

I ran `squid -X -d9` and got errors that the log files could not be written:

```
FATAL: Cannot open '/var/log/squid3/access.log' for writing.
The parent directory must be writeable by the
user 'proxy', which is the cache_effective_user
set in squid.conf.
Squid Cache (Version 3.1.20): Terminated abnormally.
```

the permissions for `/var/log/squid3` are:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 proxy proxy   4096 Apr 29 14:13 squid3
```

and inside:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 proxy proxy      0 Apr 29 06:25 access.log
-rwxrwx--- 1 proxy proxy 303469 Apr 28 23:41 access.log.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 proxy proxy  14730 Apr 29 14:47 cache.log
-rwxrwx--- 1 proxy proxy  79626 Apr 28 22:00 cache.log.1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root  root       0 Apr 27 14:09 store.log.1
```

Permissions for the cache mounted at `/cache0`

```
drwxrwxr-x  19 root proxy  4096 Apr 29 14:47 cache0
```

How can I resolve these errors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Jason. [SF] is for professional system administrators with problems in the workplace. I'll assume you're not using that Raspberry Pi at work, so your question is fine to stay here.

Answer (score 3):

The default squid user `proxy` needs write permission from the parent to all the directories it writes to; including the cache directory (`cache_dir`) and log files.

I didn't want to change the permissions of `/var` or `/var/log`, so I created a new directory `/squid3_logs` and set the log locations in `squid.conf`.

```
access_log /squid3_logs/access.log squid
cache_store_log /squid3_logs/store.log
cache_log /squid3_logs/cache.log
```

I also made sure that all the files and subdirectories in my cache (`/cache0`) had the proper permissions. When I ran the debug command `squid -X -d9` as my user, I think automatically changed the `swap.state` owner to me.

```
sudo chown proxy:proxy /cache0/swap.state
sudo chmod -R 775 /cache0
```

Now everything seems to be working.
I'm not finding any errors when I run the debug command, or when I parse the config file (`squid3 -k parse`).

Answer (score 0):

First change owner to proxy and then add user in squid.conf as given below
sudo chown proxy:proxy /usr/local/squid -R

for permission error,
you just set  cache_effective_user in squid.conf and restart squid. 
/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf

cache_effective_user proxy

This config resolved my issue

Comment: Answered 4 years ago.